# Sending an HTML email using Swift

Tags: email, symfony1, swiftmailer

I would like to send an auto-generated email with HTML body from my application using Swift.

Here is my current code:

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setFrom(array('dummy1@test.com' => 'John Doe'))
                ->setTo('dymmy2@test.com')
                ->setSubject('some subject');

            $message->setBody($this->getPartial('global/mail_partial'));

            $this->getMailer()->send($message);
```

I had already tried to change the header Content-type of the email message using some specific Swift methods but it is not working.

Comment: Hi there!

I had discovered that setting the message body as HTML also can by done passing a second argument on the $message->setBody() method, as example: $message->setBody($this->getPartial('global/mail_partial'), 'text/html');.

Anyway, thanks for the help!
Best regards!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

See:

[Sending a HTML E-Mail](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html#setting-the-body-content) (from SwiftMailer Docs)

You need to add this line to set html content-type:

```
$message->setContentType("text/html");
```

Alternatively, it can by done passing a second argument on the $message->setBody() method:

```
$message->setBody($this->getPartial('global/mail_partial'), 'text/html');.
```