# Email confirmation email with PHP, html formatting

Tags: php, html

I'm not familiar with PHP and couldn't really find a specific solution to my problem. We outsourced a project in India for a backend and part of their task was to create a login with email confirmation.

Here is part of the code:

```
$sql     = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$name' AND `status`= 1";
$result  = $db->select($sql);
$num_row = $db->numrows($sql);
if($num_row > 0) {
    $row= $db->fetcharray($sql);

    $Password   =   $row['password'];
    $body       = "Dear ".$row['fname']." <br> <br>";
    $body       .= "Your password is : ".$Password." <br> <br>";
    $body       .= "Please login with below link : <br/>";
    $body       .= SITE_URL;

    $email           = $row['email'];
    $messageSubject  = "Forgot Password : Quicksl";
    $messageBody     = $body;   

    sendContactMail(SENDER_NAME,SENDER_EMAIL,$messageBody,$email,$messageSubject);
    echo "matched";
```

However, when we receive an email, it still contains `<br>` tags from the HTML rather than rendering it as HTML.

Does it have to do anything with syntax? How can email be formatted in PHP, from the code above, so that there are no `<br>` tags  in the email, but it starts from new line?

Let me know if I did not make my question clear.

Comment: What's the code for the sendContactMail() function?

Comment: Make a quick search for "Email Mime Type"

Comment: You need to look at the code for sendContactMail, that's not a php function AFAIK so it must be custom and you will need to look at that to solve your problem.

Comment: Switch to using SwiftMailer. See their docs examples for sending HTML emails. Because you didn not specify the contents of `sendContactMail` I consider this to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112170/sending-an-html-email-using-swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending HTML email from PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058897/sending-html-email-from-php)

Answer (score 8):

You need to add

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

and pass `$headers` as the last argument of the PHP `mail` function, wherever that is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in the header that this is an html email so it will be interpreted as html rather than plain text.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$Password   =   $row['password'];
$body       = "Dear ".$row['fname']." <br> <br>";
$body       .= "Your password is : ".$Password." <br> <br>";
$body       .= "Please login with below link : <br/>";
$body       .= SITE_URL;
$email           = $row['email'];
$messageSubject  = "Forgot Password : Quicksl";
$messageBody     = $body;
```

`sendContactMail(SENDER_NAME,SENDER_EMAIL,$messageBody,$email,$messageSubject,$headers);`

Comment: where do i exactly plug that in, i just tried putting it on top but it didn't work, so do i need to specify anything else, there is a huge if/else statement for login, so im not sure where that code goes

Comment: @Vlad pass the header to ur sendContactMail function and use the header in that function as shown in the updated answer

Comment: i tried that already but it didnt work, is there a way here to attach the whole file?

Comment: Just search php mail in the search option in this site u will get ur answer all d best ... Sorry m loggin out ... Nor would have helped u out

Comment: ok, i found solution, but i cant post it till withing next 4 hours, i'll let you know what i did later

Comment: if($num_row > 0) {
  $row= $db->fetcharray($sql);
  
  $Password = $row['password'];
  
  $messageBody = ' 

Dear '.$row['fname'].', we are contacting you because you have recently requested a password reminder.

------------------------------------- 
Password: '.$Password.' 
------------------------------------- 

Please click the link below to sign in to your account: 

';
  $messageBody   .= SITE_URL;

  
  $email    = $row['email'];
  $messageSubject  = "Forgot Password : Quicksl";
 
  
  sendContactMail(SENDER_NAME,SENDER_EMAIL,$messageBody,$email,$messageSubject);

Comment: found something similar here, and i had to get rid of unnesesary functions, and basically its much simpler and it works